# Requirement for continuity of unit normal vector

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity, vector-analysis

When considering a subset $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$. If we consider $\nu$, the outward unit surface normal to $\partial \Omega$, what are the requirements of $\partial \Omega$ which will guarantee that $\nu$ is continuous and why?

Does $\partial \Omega$ have to maybe be $C^{1}$ or a Lipschitz continuous?

Thanks.

Comment: for manifolds, I think this is equivalent to orientability.

Answer (score 1):

It requires some level of smoothness, consider the following: If for example you consider the case in $3$ dimensional space, then $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{3}$ and by definition of '$C^{1}$ boundary' you have $\gamma \in C^{1}$ for each $x \in \partial \Omega$, taking $\gamma(x,y) = z$ you would define the implicit equation $F(x,y,z): = \gamma - z = 0$ and then use the theorem  that states " If a function $F$ is differentiable, the gradient of $F$ at a point is either zero, or perpendicular to the level set of $F$ at that point." Since the surface(curve in $2$ dimensions) is precisely the level set it follows that we can now define the unit normal vector as: $$\textbf{n} := \frac{\nabla F(x,y,z)}{\Vert \nabla F(x,y,z) \Vert}$$

As you can see the continuous differentiability of $\gamma$ is used in defining the unit normal vector $\textbf{n}$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\Omega$ is such that there is a regular parametrization $\gamma$ of its border, i.e. $\gamma \in C^1$ and $\nabla\gamma$ never vanish (so for example your parametrization don't get stuck a while on a point somewhere). Then you can "build" the exterior normal (at least in the case $n = 2$ and $n=3$) out of $\nabla \gamma $ and $\|\nabla \gamma \|^{-1}$.

Comment: @JohnJack I edited my post to make it more concise. I don't think it is easy to guarantee that there is always a parametrization of any domain. However saying $\partial \Omega \in C^1$ implicitly assume that there is a parametrization and this parametrization is $C^1$ (how would you interpret it else?).

Comment: I'm just asking if by parametrization $\gamma$ are you referring to the existence of a $C^{1}$ function $\gamma: \mathbb{R}^{n-1} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\gamma$ is $C^{1}$?

Comment: By parametrization of $\partial \Omega$, I mean a function $\gamma : A \subset \mathbb{R}^{n-1}  \to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\gamma(A)= \partial \Omega$.